How can I update two different app versions in the play store, one for legacy purposes and the other for modern Android versions
First of all I apologize if I couldn't make the topic quite clear in the title, but it is limited in size. I tried searching for an answer to my situation but I couldn't find anything.
I currently have an app version 1.x on the Play Store available to the public, and it is compatible with Android 7 and above.
Starting with app version 2.x there will be a deprecation for any Android below 10, this means that starting from 2.x the app is only available to devices running Android 10 or above.
App version 2.x is not yet uploaded to the play store, it is still only available on the local development environment pending completion.
My current problem is I still want to keep supporting the current app version 1.x that is available in the Play Store for a bit longer to ensure legacy devices have a stable experience, and if any bugs are found then fix them and release an update under the 1.x version.
At the same time, while the legacy version above is still receiving support, I also want to release the 2.x version, but I have yet to find any clear information explaining if this can or can't be done.
My concern is as soon as I publish app version 2.x, app version 1.x would still be available to devices with Android below 10 just fine, but I would no longer be able to push updates for app version 1.x, only for app version 2.x and above, meaning the devices with Android below 10 would no longer receive any updates on app version 1.x
So my question is, is it possible for me to keep releasing updates to my 1.x version in the Play Store and at the same time release updates for version 2.x? How can it be done, is it just normal upload or a different process? If it is possible, can anyone post where in their official documentation that is disclosed/explained?
Much appreciated for the help.

This seems similar to your prior question also making sure you've seen: https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api and issues for bundletool for aab creation/limits https://github.com/google/bundletool/issues/348

Note generally the app publisher would support the legacy APIs within the main release until a new minSDK and end support for older devices. Note as of 2024-06, Android 10+ only has about 80% device coverage. This way the versionCode is consistently increasing and matches Google Play's app bundle expectation.

Unfortunately I do not have the option of doing that, otherwise it would have been simpler.

It looks like there is no direct way to do this.
But in order to achieve this you can upload same app with two different applications id . As they are two different applications.
Although this is a suggestion not a solution.
